# Understanding SDWebImage and lazy loading

Tags: iphone, ios, lazy-loading, sdwebimage

I need to implement some lazy loading of images in a tableView and I've read a lot about SDWebImage, but I couldn't understand how it really works. I hope I can get answers here.

So with SDWebImage, what will happend if I scroll really fast, say 100 cells/second? If those images is'nt stored in memory - will SDWebImage download all those images, save them and decompress them?

Can I tell SDWebImage to save images to *"library/Application Support"* instead of saving them in cache dir?  I only need my images to lazy load the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't really call it 'lazy loading' in the normal sense since SDWebImage is not what determines if your images are loaded lazily.  SDWebImage loads the images when you call one of its `setImageWithURL:` methods (variations include placeholder, no placeholder, completion block, progress block, etc).  It's up to you to call the method only when the cell is drawn/shown, that is what determines if you're lazy loading.  If you create all your cells first (not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or an equivalent method) then you won't be lazy loading. SDWebImage has nothing to do with this.

What SDWebImage does is loads the image in a background thread so you're not blocking the UI/main thread when this downloading is going on.  Furthermore, it will also disk-cache all the images you've downloaded and will NEVER re-download an image from the same URL (this is both a plus and a minus). You can clear the cache based on time, and I believe the master branch added support for a disk-limit for the cache as well (this is relevant if you're using CocoaPods since it doesn't default to 'master' and you won't get this functionality - they might have updated the CocoaPods version/tag, you'd have to confirm).

Now, just for some extra info - you'll read literature that mentions that iOS NSURLCache (5.0+) already implements disk caching of raw HTTP responses.  However, this means that each time the image is pulled from cache, it has to transform the raw data into a UIImage. SDWebImage, on the other hand, caches the UIImage representation which saves you this overhead.

With regards to changing the destination folder, can I ask why?  SDWebImage caches images semi-forever (depending on your cache settings if you choose to set them).  Saved location doesn't really affect caching - you could modify the code to save it somewhere else. Below is the relevant section from SDImageCache.m that you could change - would need to review the rest of the SDWebImage code to make sure it doesn't break anything:

```
    // Init the disk cache
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    _diskCachePath = [paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fullNamespace];
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you need more info.

UPDATE: To specifically answer this:

So with SDWebImage, what will happend if I scroll really fast, say 100 cells/second? If those images is'nt stored in memory - will SDWebImage download all those images, save them and decompress them?

Those images will be downloaded (and saved to the disk cache, since this is the default behavior). The image data will be tossed out of memory when you reuse your cells (assuming that you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`). If you scroll back up, SDWebImage will know if that particular URL has already been downloaded, and will use the version stored in the disk cache. If you scrolled so fast that the download wasn't able to complete before that cell was re-used, then when you scroll back up, it will again attempt to download the image. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Wow this helped me alot!! 
Do I have to cancel downloads myself or maybe that is'nt a  big problem? I thought that if I start making to many request at once it's taking to much time to get the visible cells images.

Comment: Regarding storage folder, my images never change, so I want to store them more permanently, but maybe the cache storage is sufficient after all. 
It's nice to know how I can change it, but as you said I proberbly need to check if that doesn't break anything.

Comment: Canceling downloads isn't a big problem, for the same reason I mentioned in the 'updated' paragraph - basically if you're reusing cells, the UIImageView in those cells get re-used, and from my brief reading, each time you call `setImageWithURL:` it first cancels all operations previously associated with that UIImageView, so no, you don't have hundreds of download operations queued.

Comment: @Jai Govindani: Don't know whether operations are really cancelled but it does happen that if you scroll up and down very fast, you will end up with images being misplaced on the wrong cells so I suspect SDWebImage does not handle this properly / automatically (don't yet know if it's a bug or if we simply have to handle it ourselves, but this is not that easy)

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci when I answered this question last year I remember going in to look at the code that's in the UIImageView category and definitely remember that all operations on that UIImageView were canceled first. If your images are being misplaced in the wrong cells then I would definitely investigate your cell drawing code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - every case of this I've seen has had to do with drawing code and not the library. Feel free to open up a question and share your code, will help investigate!

Comment: @JaiGovindani it seems I am not the only one facing this issue : [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727165/sdwebimage-operations-not-being-canceled) I implemented a custom operation management / cancelation and that works but the built-in method doesn't. I checked the source and I agree with you that the code calls cancelCurrentImageUpload each time you setImageUrl so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

i have recently implemented it with uitableview

you have to do 3 things and it will handle everything by itself

1.add SDWebImage complete folder in your project(make sure to check copy checkbox while adding)
2.add this line at the top of that class where you want to handle lazyloading #import UIImageView+WebCache.h".

1. finally use this line in tableviewcell

[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:(NSURL *) placeholderImage:(UIImage *)]

thats it :) cheers mate. i have also searched a lot for this problem